# Does calling an async method immediately running its commands

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I got this code:

```
static async Task AsynchronousProcessing()
{  
    Task<string> t1 = GetInfoAsync("Task 1", 3);  
    Task<string> t2 = GetInfoAsync("Task 2", 5);  
    string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);  
    foreach (string result in results)  
    {    
      WriteLine(result);  
    }
}

static async Task<string> GetInfoAsync(string name, int seconds)
{  
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));   
    return  "hi";
}
```

When reaching the line `Task<string> t1 = GetInfoAsync("Task 1", 3);`, will it already start asynchronously with the `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));` and move on to the rest of the method, or will it return immediatly a task without actually starting it?

And if it won't start when calling the method, will the tasks start only when calling the `Task.WhenAll(t1,t2)`? Since if it doesn't start right away, I would expect to see `GetInfoAsync` doing something like `return new Task<string>(() => ...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend reading my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

In summary, all `async` methods begin executing synchronously. So when `AsynchronousProcessing` calls `GetInfoAsync`, then `GetInfoAsync` begins running, synchronously, just like any other method. An `async` method can become asynchronous when there is an `await`. In this case, `GetInfoAsync` calls `Task.Delay` (again, synchronously, just like a regular method call), and then passes its `Task` to `await`. At this point, `await` will examine the task; if it is already complete, then it will continue running synchronously; otherwise, it will act asynchronously and return an incomplete task from `GetInfoAsync`.

The tasks returned from `async` methods are in progress. I don't usually use the term "running", because they are not actually running code on a CPU and because the task status is not actually `Running`. [This "asynchronous in-progress" state is unfortunately named `WaitingForActivation`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html) (even though it's not waiting for anything).

> Since if it doesn't start right away, I would expect to see GetInfoAsync doing something like return new Task(() => ...);

The `async` keyword handles the creation of the task. As noted above, the tasks are "hot" or "in progress". This is not the same as "running" or "started", both of which imply tasks that run CPU code. [There are two types of tasks: what I call Delegate Tasks and Promise Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html). The ones returned from `async` methods are Promise Tasks.

> If there aren't any new threads with await, then how will they run in parallel?

They run *concurrently* (not in *parallel*, since there is no additional thread blocked on the delay).

However, when the `await Task.Delay(..)` completes, then there could possibly be another thread used. The `await` will [resume on its captured context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and execute the `return "hi";` in that context. If the captured context is a thread pool context, then that one line of code will be executed on a thread pool thread. The `async` state machine translates the `return` into code that completes the task that was previously returned from that `async` method.

Comment: "if it is already complete, then it will continue running *asynchronously*; " - Is that a typo? From the linked article: "Await examines that awaitable to see if it has already completed; if the awaitable has already completed, then the method just continues running (*synchronously*, just like a regular method)."

Comment: @ScottHannen: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't have known the difference except that I recently read the article, which was illuminating.

Comment: Nice async intro! I liked it. Will help me to improve my knowledge, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`GetInfoAsync` is called and runs synchronously just as usual until it hits the `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds))` line. It then returns an uncompleted task back to the calling `AsynchronousProcessing()` method.

So, yes, the task is indeed being started when you call the method, i.e. you don't have to await `GetInfoAsync` for the `Task.Delay` method to get called.

Comment: So in the case of this method, will the 2 tasks run in parallel? Without new threads?

Comment: @YonatanNir: Yes, the second call to `Task.Delay` will happen just after the first call to `GetInfoAsync` has returned the uncompleted task and `GetInfoAsync` has been called again. If you put a breakpoint on the line that returns "hi" and call both methods with the same value for the `seconds` argument, you should note that the breakpoint will be triggered twice after `seconds` seconds.

Comment: Regarding the tasks running together.. If there aren't any new threads with await, then how will they run in parallel?

Comment: @YonatanNir: `Task.Delay` starts a timer and completes its returned task when the timer elapses. The actual calls to `GetInfoAsync` don't really run in parallel since they return almost immediately. But the timers and the  `Task.Delay` tasks do run in parallel.